# How do we know if a matrix is in a general linear group?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have that $$A = \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}$$ $$B = \begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}$$$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}3&2&2\\2&1&2\\-1&3&1\end{bmatrix}$$$$D = \begin{bmatrix}-3&-1&2\\1&-3&-1\\3&0&-2\end{bmatrix}$$ My question is how do we know if a matrix is in G$L_n$($\mathbb{Z})$? My understanding of how general linear groups is that G$L_n$($\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of matrices such that {$n\times n$ matrices with real coefficients and $\det(A) \neq 0$}. Therefore, since all of them have real coefficients and all of their determinants are nonzero, are all of them in G$L_n$($\mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the requirements for a set to be a group is that every element have an inverse element in the group.

$GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is the set of matrices with integer entries that also has an inverse with integer entries.

$GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is the set of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries and non-zero determinants.  The non-zero determinant means that every matrix in the group has an inverse matrix that is also in the group.

Looking at $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ we can't take all matrices with non-zero determinants.  It is not a sufficiently restrictive condition.  This should illustrate the problem.

$\begin{bmatrix} 3&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac {1}{2}&-\frac {1}{4}\\-\frac {1}{2}&\frac {3}{4}\end{bmatrix}$

$GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is the set of matrices with integer entries that have determinants equal to $\pm 1$ will do the trick.

Comment: I see....I believe I was confusing G$L_n$($\mathbb{R})$ with G$L_n$($\mathbb{Z})$. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It will be in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ if and only if its determinant is $\pm1$. This is part of a general result that a matrix with coefficients in $R$ is invertible over $R$ (that is, has an inverse with coefficients in $R$) if and only if its determinant is a unit in $R$. The proof is the same as the one you know for a field. The formula for the inverse of a matrix requires only that the determinant be invertible as an element of the ring.

Comment: A minor observation: "The proof is the same as the one you know for a field". Some prove that $A$ not being invertible implies $\det(A)=0$ in the context of fields using linear algebra arguments about the fact that the linear map will not be surjective, thus the collumns must be linearly dependent. You could clarify the proof you are alluding to (which is probably the use of the explicit formula of the inverse in terms of the adjugate matrix).